# Ubuntu 12.04 unable to mount first partition of internal hard drive

Tags: linux, ubuntu, hard-drive, mount

I used to have Windows 7 installed, but some day it crashed (or the hard drive crashed, I'm not sure) and the laptop wouldn't boot.

So I decided to boot Ubuntu 12.04 from a CD and it worked. For some reason though it couldn't read the first partition of my internal hard drive (the hard drive was divided in two partitions, C and D, but Ubuntu couldn't mount C).

Comment: Did you try to mount it explicitly or did you just start the live CD and look what it does automatically ?